# Custom Signal handler in C. for (Alt+F4)

Tags: c, client-server, signal-handling

In C programming, ctrl+c is seen as a signal interrupt and it shuts down the program, which I would call a graceful shutdown. But in some unforeseen circumstances, can the server shutdown be handled like the ctrl+c exit?

History: I have 2 servers, A and B. A can be considered as a central server which acts like a repository for many servers that can register to it. Now, B is another server on the same network, when it runs, it registers with A. Next, when i press ctrl+c on the terminal instance of serverB, the server shuts down and also smoothly deregisters itself from the central server (A).

However, if I just close the terminal of B, the server A assumes that the serverB is still active, but in reality it has terminated.

So to handle this scenario, is there any way to consider alt+f4 as a signal interrupt, so that i replicate the scenario of a smooth exit?

Any guidance would be useful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might depend on what operating system you are running this on, but have you tried atexit? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/

Comment: Hi @rmfeldt, I am running the applications on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: In that case you should try to catch the SIGHUP signal.

Comment: Can it be configured to catch ALT+F4? I mean, ctrl+c is configured in a way that there is a smooth exit

Comment: When the terminal is closing it should send SIGHUP to all processes that were started from it. So it is not just for ALT+F4, but for any reason that the terminal was closed. Save for a kill -9, i doubt it will send it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guys told before me you can register signal handler function for SIGHUP signal with call

```
signal(SIGINT,sig_handler)
```

Also If I'm not wrong if you use gcc of course you might use function attribute

```
__attribute__((destructor[(priority)]))
```

If you implement something to smoothly disconnect from desired server it will work for any type of termination of your program (except SEGFAULT).

But still signal handler will be best solution